# How to combine two visual studio online environments to work with a single git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

We have two separate visual studio online environments. However, we would like to have one git repository that is synced across the vso environments. So both teams can pull/push and have both the remotes in sync.

Comment: How do you want the users from another VSTS account pull/push the git repo, pull/push only from client side (such as by git command line, VS etc) or also can access the git repo from VSTS web page?

Comment: It would already be useful if could sync the code from git command line/VS. 
Acces to VSTS pages would be extremely useful for pull-request, but that is a "nice to have".

Comment: I added an answer with both situations. And if you want to pull/push from client side, the option 1 is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume share repoA from VSTS accountA to the users of VSTS accountB. Then you can follow below options based on the situation you need:

#### Option 1: users from VSTS accountB can only pull/push in client side

For this situation, you just need to provider a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) from accountA to the users of account.

And the minimum scope of the PAT is only select Code (read and write).

[image]

#### Option 2: users from VSTS accountB can access to repoA from VSTS accountA web page

You can also add users from accountB to accountA, and then set permissions for the users, so that they can access to the repoA (such as create pull request) from VSTS web page.

**Note:** if users with basic access level are more than 5, you need to pay for the additional users with basic access level.

Comment: Thank you for your response, 

I have 2 more questions:

Would it be possible to include users from the different vso accounts as stakeholders e.g. all AccountA users will be stakeholders at AccountB. 
And therefore have access to work items across two visual studio online environments?

Secondly, will option 1(PAT) combined with stakeholder rights give access to see the pull-request screen in vso? or track the pull-request by using some other git tool.

Comment: @Igor 1. Yes, you can add users from accountA as stakeholders for accountB, so that users from accountA can access to the work items of accountB. 2. PAT and stakeholder rights has no effect which each other. Users who have stakeholder rights can not view code Hub, they can only access to the repo by git command line or VS etc.

Comment: @lgor Does the answer helps you solve the problems? If yes, can you mark the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions :)